# Can I make a Vbscript wait for scheduled shutdowns to occur?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I want to make a Vbscript wait until a scheduled shutdown occurs, Then launch a batch file to cancel it. I know enough to launch a batch from a vbs and how to cancel a shutdown but I need to know how to make a vbs that waits until shutdown occurs. (tell me if this is not possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VBS file to start a hidden batch file.

```
 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """c:\windows\system32\cmd /c Mybat.bat""", 0, false
```

The batch file cancelling a shutdown every 60 secs

```
:Loop
Shutdown /a
timeout /t 60
Goto Loop
```

Comment: Worked but i needed to change the code a bit for it to work properly.

Comment: CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """Mybat.bat""", 0, false